# Laravel Token Mismatch error while uploading the image

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading

I have purchased a script from codecanyon which is used to upload images. But while I am uploading the image, I got an error:

```
(1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your blade file:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: <input id="my-file-selector" accept="image/*" required name="photo" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());">

Comment: But error is related to token so you are missing to add token in your form

Comment: @PintRaj this is not error related to your code....This error related to Laravel token